# Does P2SH unlocking script only consist of operants?

Tags: p2sh

I have a question about the P2SH unlocking script. Can I put common operants and operators in the P2SH unlocking script? And if yes, how can I create such script?

e.g.

unlocing script: `<sig1> <pk1> CHECKSIG <pk1> <redeem script>`

redeem script:  `HASH160 <address> EQUALVERIFY <sig2> <pk2> CHECKSIG`

Answer (score 1):

> Can I put common operants and operators in the P2SH unlocking script?

No, you can not.

1) Unlocking script ( `scriptSig` ) should contain only push operations, yours contains OP_CHECKSIG

2) It has no sense to put signature `sig2` into the redeem script and check it with OP_CHECKSIG because such script definetely fail on execution. If you want to put any data in the `redeem` script - you can do it in other way.

Comment: Thanks your answer. I appreciate it. But for your second point, you mean, signature values can't be included in redeem script?

Comment: Trivia: If you can mine nonstandard transactions, you can put non-push operations in unlock script.

Comment: theoretically yes, but do you have an tutorial of building my previous transactions?

Comment: @MCCCS Pushonly is actually consensus mandatory for P2SH and P2WSH. For non-wrapped scripts it is just a standardness rule.